# Объяснить работу defaultdict

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

Пытаюсь с помощью defaultdict группировать данные, благодаря свойству уникальности ключей в словаре. Есть переменная со списком кортежей: `request = [(1, 'email1@.com'),(2, 'Email1@.com'),(3, 'email2@.com'),(4, 'email3@.com'),(5, 'EMAIL3@.com')]`. Я осуществляю группировку по email, предварительно переводя его в нижний регистр таким образом:

```
players = defaultdict(list)
{players[_i[1].lower()].append(_i[0]) for _i in tqdm.tqdm(request) if _i[0] not in players[_i[1]]}
```

По моим ожиданиям ответ должен получиться такой:

```
{
'email1@.com': [1, 2], 
'email2@.com': [3], 
'email3@.com': [4, 5]
}
```

Но почему-то в результате получаю такое:

```
{
'email1@.com': [1, 2], 
'Email1@.com': [], 
'email2@.com': [3], 
'email3@.com': [4, 5], 
'EMAIL3@.com': []
}
```

Можете объяснить, почему?

P.S. tqdm сторонняя библиотека для визуализации процесса выполнения прохода по списку.

Comment: Непонятнки у вас с lower(), но вопрос почему-то про "работу словаря".

Comment: А в чем непонятки у меня с lower()? Я, вроде, понимаю как он работает.

Comment: `{players[_i[1].lower()].append(_i[0]) for _i in tqdm.tqdm(request) if _i[0] not in players[_i[1]]}` - это зло. Не нужно так использовать comprehensions. Лучше в таких случаях использовать обычный цикл.

Answer (score 2):

потому что запись добавляется в словарь в момент попытки обратиться к ней. если ключа нет.

```
players = defaultdict(list)
{players[_i[1].lower()].append(_i[0]) for _i in tqdm.tqdm(request) if _i[0] not in players[_i[1]]}
```

Давайте для начала перепишем пример. чтобы мне было проще указать место.

```
1for _i in tqdm.tqdm(request):
2    if _i[0] not in players[_i[1]]:
3        players[_i[1].lower()].append(_i[0])
```

во второй строке в условии идет получение значения по ключу **players[_i[1]]**. в этот самый момент добавляется запись. если ключа нет. т.е. вместо получения стандартной ошибки KeyError. а так как тут нет перевода в нижний регистр то вы и получаете то что получаете.

```
players = defaultdict(list)
{players[_i[1].lower()].append(_i[0]) for _i in tqdm.tqdm(request) if _i[0] not in players[_i[1].lower()]}
```

можно убрать проверку уникальности

```
players = defaultdict(set)
{players[_i[1].lower()].add(_i[0]) for _i in tqdm.tqdm(request)}
```

Comment: Проверку уникальности убрать не могу, а решение работает. Только хочу уточнить, получается, запись добавляется уже в тот момент, когда я к кортежу обращаюсь?

Comment: исправил. так понятнее?

Comment: Да, большое спасибо! Забыл о том, что при обращении к словарю по ключу создается ключ, если его нет из-за этого и была проблема.